# How to handle special characters in IndexedDB keyPath attribute when creating indexes?

Tags: javascript, browser, nosql, local-storage, indexeddb

I'm working with IndexedDB and trying to create indexes with special characters in the keyPath attribute. However, I'm encountering issues when using special characters like "@" or "&" in the keyPath. The createIndex method doesn't seem to support special characters in the keyPath.

I've tried replacing the special characters with custom strings or encoding them, but it didn't work as expected. I'm wondering if there's a recommended approach or workaround for using special characters in the keyPath attribute while creating indexes in IndexedDB.

I've already checked the documentation for IndexedDB about keypath constraint and searched on Stack Overflow for similar issues, but I couldn't find a clear solution. Some suggestions involved replacing or encoding the special characters, but those approaches didn't work as expected.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
const db = ...; // Opened IndexedDB database
const objectStore = db.createObjectStore("myStore", { keyPath: "title@" });
const index = objectStore.createIndex("myIndex", "text@");
```

Is there a way to handle special characters in the keyPath attribute when creating indexes in IndexedDB? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a recommended way, but you can try using base64 encoding like `btoa('text@')`. You can then decode it using `atob`

Comment: Yes, tried using encoding functions in JS but its not working. throws the same error

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createIndex' on 'IDBObjectStore': The keyPath argument contains an invalid key path.

Answer (score 0):

Per spec https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-path-construct steps in a key path are restricted to JS identifiers. The intent is that if you have an object like:

`{ id: 123, name: { full: "Alice Aardvark", nick: "ardy" } }`

... then just as you'd write `o.name.nick` in JS you'd use `"name.nick"` as a key path. If your object property keys are not simple identifiers, then you're out of luck - you'll need to massage the data before storing it.

For example, if from JS you'd need to write `o["text@"]` then you can't use a key path to pull the "text@" property out automatically. You'll need to do something like `o.text = o["text@"]; delete o["text@"]` before storing, use "text" as a keypath, and revert the change after retrieving a value. (The delete is not strictly necessary, but would avoid duplicate storage.

There is no escaping mechanism to make this "just" work with key paths without modifying the object data structure.